# Insertion vs epoxide formation

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, organosulfur-compounds

How can it be explained that in the first reaction mentioned below, a 7-membered ring dominates when the leaving group is nitrogen and an epoxide forms when the leaving group is dimethyl sulfide?

This is quoted from "*The Art of Writing Reasonable Organic Reaction Mechanisms*", Second Edition by Robert B. Grossman, [DOI: 10.1007/b97257](https://doi.org/10.1007/b97257).

> The $\ce{C}$ in diazomethane is nucleophilic. The product of attack of diazomethane on the carbonyl $\ce{C}$ has a leaving group a to the alkoxide, so either a 1,2 alkyl shift or direct nucleophilic displacement can occur. The insertion product happens to dominate with $\ce{H2\overset{-}{C}-\overset{+}{N}_2}$, but with $\ce{H2\overset{-}{C}-\overset{+}{S}Me2}$ the epoxide dominates.
>
> [image]